# Why is this question highly upvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, up-votes

Why is https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/66/the-most-common-mistakes-for-newbies-recording highly upvoted? The question asks,

> What are the the most common mistakes that new engineers tend to make when recording and mixing down their tracks?

To me, this question seems to be bad subjective for the following reasons:

- It doesn't ask for help with any particular problem.
- It asks for a list of opinions.
- There can't be one good, final answer to the question - there are a lot of different problems that new engineers might face!

I'm a relatively inexperienced user, so I'm willing to admit that I see things the wrong way. Apparently, I'm not seeing this question the same way as 39 other upvoters. Why is this question high-quality?

Comment: It's old... It was likely one of the first questions on the site?  The decisions about what would be acceptable and unacceptable were still being made?

Comment: Ah. It was originally posted in December 2010. That makes a lot more sense now. =P

Comment: Perhaps the question should be locked as historically meaningful but not representative of questions that would be high quality now?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of locking the post.  It is fairly open ended and it does look like a question that could generate bad answers in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post has now been locked per your suggestion.